# Can I use enunciate module to only display swagger UI?

Tags: jax-rs, swagger, spring-web, enunciate

I have a Java Spring-based RESTful API that uses enunciate for auto-generated documentation. I am upgrading from Enunciate 1.x to 2.8.0, and would like to stop using the base Enunciate documentation in favor of SwaggerUI ONLY.

Is there a way to suppress the base enunciate documentation and generate only the swagger docs?

Comment: Are you just concerned about bloat? When I configure my "/docs" URI, I point it to "apidocs/ui" (the location of the Swagger UI), so no one can ever access the base docs via the service (but they are shipped around with the service artifact...)